# Display UI like facebook messenger in Android java programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-widget, android-xml

**Image**

[image: http://imgur.com/llytvyQ] --

I want to achieve something like this in above image

I have to loop through this json array to get all my datas;
the data contained in my json array are for example

```
{
 'img' : http:\\.....
 'name' : XYZ
 'msg' : xyz
 'time' : abc
}

//this is where I am tring to append everything
final LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout)main.findViewById(R.id.mainL); 

for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) { 
    try {
        JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
        //here components must be created and added to view
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I just want to know the **how do you programmatically style the views**(textview,imageview etc) like in the above image.
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason you need to create the view programmatically? I would create a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView` and create your view in `getView` in your custom adapter.

Comment: since i am getting the data from server i dont know how many listview i need to create so i need to make a loop n do it programatically ! @JaredRummler do you have a better idea ?

Comment: I would first parse the JSON and load each JSONObject into a class and put each object you created in an `ArrayList`. Then pass that `ArrayList` to your custom adapter and get the info you need with `getItem(position)`.

Comment: *Call this mother___ing ass___le* in the pic is why I didnt wanna post it xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the image you are looking at is actually a `ListView` serving custom-made views.

How does that work?
You will need to subclass the `BaseAdapter` class. This subclass will contain the underlying data which in your case you are getting as a JSON-formatted reply from the web-server.

When the `getView()` of the `BaseAdapter` subclass is called, you can inflate a layout that contains an `ImageView` and `TextView`s to display the data onscreen.

Comment: Im gettin something but can u give a lil bit of code to make it clearer ? @lilchild

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just for future visitors, since the question was asked long day ago. At first, I will just redirect you to my [GitHub page](https://github.com/b-Istiak-s/RetrofitRecyclerView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/istiak/getdatabyretrofit) where I used RecyclerView to show data and Retrofit to call data. I used [Volley](https://github.com/b-Istiak-s/RecyclerViewInMysqlDatabase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/istiak/recyclerviewinmysqldatabase/MainActivity.java) also. Finally, let me show simple way to load data to recyclerview.

You need an extra class call it CustomAdapter.

```java
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    Context context;
    private String countryList[];
    private int imgList[];

    //constructor
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String countryList[],int imgList[]) {
        this.context = context;
        this.countryList = countryList;
        this.imgList=imgList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // inflate the item Layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(view); // pass the view to View Holder
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myHolder, final int position) {

        myHolder.txtName.setText(countryList[position]);
        myHolder.imgCountry.setImageResource(imgList[position]);
        // implement setOnClickListener event on item view.
        myHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // display a toast with person name on item click
                Toast.makeText(context, countryList[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return countryList.length;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtName;
        ImageView imgCountry;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // get the reference of item view's
            txtName =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            imgCountry =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_flag);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the MainActivity, you have declare a LayoutManager for RecyclerView and have to call CustomAdapter to load data in RecyclerView.

```java
String countryList[]={"Bangladesh","India","China","Australia","America","New Zealand","Portugal"};
    int imgList[]={R.drawable.bd,R.drawable.india,R.drawable.china,R.drawable.australia,R.drawable.america,R.drawable.new_zealand,R.drawable.portugle};

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the reference of RecyclerView
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        // set a LinearLayoutManager with default vertical orientation
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());


        // set a LinearLayoutManager with default Horizontal orientation
        // LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        //  call the constructor of CustomAdapter to send the reference and data to Adapter
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,countryList, imgList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter); // set the Adapter to RecyclerView

    }
```

activity_main.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

items.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_flag"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the [github repository](https://github.com/b-Istiak-s/RecyclerView). If you are calling data from server then visit my Volley repo.